# Adding PDF to backside printing for Data Driven Pages?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, printing, pdf, data-driven-pages

Is there an easy way to add a PDF to the backside of each map printed using data driven pages?

I know I could print one sided and then reinsert the printed pages upside down, and print the PDF on the reverse side. However, we may deliver this to our client digitally and would like it to be setup for them.

For example, I have data driven pages set up for 50 parcels. Each map printed will show a single parcel's data. I need a generic PDF to print on the backside of each of these 50 maps.

Comment: Are you using arcPy to do this?  I think you can rotate the data frame in arcpy which you could always do for every even number page or something.

Comment: PDFs don't really have 'sides'. It sounds more like you need to insert a standard form page in between each of your DDP pages so that if you print the overall pdf to paper as double-sided you'll get the result you want. And it'd probably be easier to do this in a pdf editor if you have one. DDP is rather limited when it comes to setting up complex multipage documents as single files. Are you wanting one file, or 50?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this I would use ArcPy with Data Driven Pages.  There is some sample code in the help document entitled [Creating a map book with facing pages](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Creating_a_map_book_with_facing_pages/00s90000002p000000/) which has all the necessary coding patterns but is a bit more complicated than what you want to do.

To create your PDF you just need to use `arcpy.mapping` to loop through your data driven pages one at a time, and then on each iteration to:

1. export the current page using `exportToPDF` and then `appendPages`
2. use `appendPages` again to put a copy of your generic PDF next