# ArcGIS Data driven pages Two MXD in one pdf

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, data-driven-pages

I have two mxd files created by data driven pages.

How is it possible to export them to one pdf file?

First a page from the first mxd file, then the first page of the second mxd file.
Next the second page from the first mxd file, then the second page of mxd file.

Comment: I think the answer to this is in the answer to the duplicate: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/146534/115 Especially this linked help: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Creating_a_map_book_with_facing_pages/00s90000002p000000/

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a couple pages, I would suggest using any PDF editor software such as Adobe Acrobat. If you do not have a license, there are open source and free alternatives out there to combine and organize your pages. [PDF Forge](http://www.pdfforge.org/) is one I used when I did not have the proper license level of Adobe.

If you are going to be creating frequent PDFs with multiple MXDs with more than a couple pages, you will need to create a script. That is going to be more time-consuming. As long as you only need 4 total pages the fastest way will be what I mentioned above.